# Contact Checkbox field based on Contact's Email Domain

Tags: email, formula-field, contact, admin

I need to create a checkbox on Contacts that is automatically flagged when the contact has an email address that falls within a specified list of domains (i.e., "@xyz.com", "@abc.com")?   The list will be relatively static, and consists of 6 or 7 domains.

If possible, I need to do this without Apex or scripting (I'm not a developer---just a beginner Admin).

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: This is possible with a formula field. Have you tried to write this formula field yet? If not, you should give it a try. If you have, please [edit] your question to include your attempt as well as pointing out where, precisely, you're stuck. In either case, referencing the [Formula Operators and Functions documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Derek says, you should really give this a go.  But here's an answer if you don't have the time:

1. Create a new formula field on the Contact object that is of type Checkbox
2. Use the following formula, substituting the abc.com etc with the domains you want to flag:

   IF(OR(CONTAINS(Email,'@xyz.com'),CONTAINS(Email,'@abc.com'),CONTAINS(Email,'@123.com')),true,false)

Use as many CONTAINS functions as you have domains you want to flag.

This consists of three functions:

IF(expression, value-returned-if-true, value-returned-if-false)

OR(ifThisExpression,orThisExpression,orThatExpression) //returns true if any of those expressions are true

CONTAINS(string,stringToCompare) //returns true if the string contains the stringToCompare

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks...And sorry for the newbie question!

Comment: That's ok Bob we were all newbies once